# ImGui slowing down when using cpr

Tags: c++, imgui

So I am trying to make a changelogs sort of thing

```
 auto request = cpr::Post (
                            cpr::Url{ "http://leoservices.xyz/pchangelogs.php" }
                        );
                        auto response = request.text.c_str ( );
                        sprintf_s ( G->changelogsBuffer , "Changelogs: %s" , response );
                        ImGui::InputTextMultiline ( "##Change Logs" , G->changelogsBuffer , sizeof ( G->changelogsBuffer ) , ImVec2 ( ImGui::GetContentRegionAvail ( ).x - 10 , ImGui::GetContentRegionAvail ( ).y - 58 ) , ImGuiInputTextFlags_ReadOnly | ImGuiInputTextFlags_NoMarkEdited );
```

This is the current code but when I got to this tab it just starts laggin' is their something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Move CPR stuff to a different thread?

Comment: Show us how exactly you did it.